# Angular 2 router when navigate to another url not reseting the outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have route with another outlet called compose, for example:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: 'about', compose: 'new-message'}}]">About with compose</a>
```

When I clicking on the link the URL is:

```
http://localhost:4200/about(compose:new-message)
```

That's fine, but when I clicking on this:

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
```

The URL is still with the outlet:

```
http://localhost:4200/home(compose:new-message)
```

The solution I found is to reset the outlet like this:

```
 <a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: 'home', compose: null}}]">Home</a>
```

But this is so verbose and annoying, because I will need do this in every link, There is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

When you use [routerlink] it generates href dynamically on the basis of every URL change.

You can work on this as below:

```
//url = '/home' in ur case
<a (click)='changeRoute(url)'></a>
```

In your component add below function.

```
routChange(url){
   this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
}
```